# Web service in VS 2022?

Tags: c#, web-services

What is the equivalent of [DataContract] and [DataMember] in VS 2022?

I used to use these keywords in VS 2019 but they don't seem to work in 2022!

Comment: GRPC is a modern replacement for SOAP. You might consider looking into it instead.

Comment: In addition to Crowcoder's excellent suggestion, you'd need to supply more details before we can help you. C# languages features, such as these two attributes are generally not dependent on the version of VS (unless we're talking about new features introduced with later versions of C#, which is not your case), so both `[DataContract]` and [`DataMember]` work exactly the same way in VS 2022 as they did in previous version. Most likely, you're trying to use them in a non-WCF web service, but without any more detail, I'm only guessing